# Enhanced FrogRiverN

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I'm working some programming exercises. This one has been quite well known and answered in different places.

FrogRiverOne
Find the earliest time when a frog can jump to the other side of a river.
https://codility.com/programmers/task/frog_river_one/

My question is, what if the Frog can jump a distance of D? how can we find the shortest time to cross the river, **with the best runtime complexity**? Thanks!

```
int solution(int X, vector<int> &A, int D);    // frog can jumps from 1 to D steps
```

Comment: my bad, I think you are right. How about O(n lg n), do you think it's good enough?

Comment: I was told it could be O(N+X)
N is size of array, X is river width

Comment: Good to know that...I suggest you put this information into the question as well, as this gives others a direction to think :)

Answer (score 1):

I think shole's greedy solution is almost correct. If you include a recursive propagation step when you change `Current_Pos`, you will ensure that the frog is always at the front-most position.

Here is an alternative that avoids the recursion:

Use an occupancy array that stores for each position if there is a leaf. And use a union-find data structure with nodes for every position. The union-find data structure will keep track of nodes that can be reached from each other (i.e. connected components). The task then is to find the first point in time when both river banks are connected.

To find this, do the following: Every time a new leaf comes into play, mark its position as occupied. Then, unite the node in the union-find data structure with every other occupied node that is reachable from this position (`-D` to `+D`). Finally, check if both river banks are connected. Overall time complexity is `O(ND+X)`.

Which of the two solutions is faster depends on the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on c# with Linq :

```
private static int FrogRiverOne(int X,int[] A)
    {
        if (Enumerable.Range(1,X).Except(A).Any()) { return -1; }
        var orderBy = A.Select((y, z) => new { y, z }).GroupBy(a => a.y).Select(a => 
              { var ff = a.Min(xe => xe.z); return new { a,ff }; });
        var second = orderBy.Max(xe => xe.ff);
        return second;

    }
```